# iOS Core Data: store relationship to ANY NSManagedObject in different entity

Tags: core-data, ios5

I would like to implement a table which references objects of any type, e.g. an archive table which references objects from person, address, ...

Naturally, I don't like to make an extra relationship for every table (archivedPersons, archivedAddresses etc.). Is there a way to simply have a relationship to "NSManagedObject"? It would also be no problem to save a property "NSManagedObject" and have a single entry for every archived object.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are kinda stuck.  You can create a base entity, and inherit the others from it.  Then, you can just make one to-many relationship to the Base entity.

This works great, and like you think it should.  However, there is one big drawback.  All sub-entities are grouped into a single table.  Thus, there is a column for each attribute in the sub-entities.  If you don't have a large database, this may be OK.  Or, if your rows are about 70% filled, then that may be OK too.  You should examine how much space you will be wasting to see if this option really works for you.

The other alternative is to store a set of object ids, and manually fetch the referenced objects.

Or, as you stated earlier, use one reference for each entity type.

Comment: I also thought about going with the base-entity-solution, but that drawback mackes me think again. My base entity will only have a few BOOL fields - so that should not be THAT problematic, is it? The entities inherit the attributes only from their superclass, don't they? Or is it really one table with ALL the attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but you'll have to some coding yourself. If I understand you correctly, you want a to-many relationship to objects of any kind.

What you would need to do is to store a (possibly ordered) set of objects IDs with the object. You would then have to convert from managed object <-> set of object IDs using one of the techniques described in the Core Data documentation's *Non-Standard Persistent Attributes* section.

If you have a set of URL (from `-[NSManagedObjectID URIRepresentation]`) you can serialize & unserialize that using `NSPropertyListSerialization`.

One you have a set of URLs you can convert those to objects. This is where things get slightly tricky. You *have* to use `NSFetchRequest` but you can only do that per entity. Therefore you will be best off storing the entity name with the objectIDs.

Since fetch requests are expensive, you might want to use `-[NSManagedObjectContext objectRegisteredForID:` for all object IDs that you're trying to turn into objects. If this method returns non-`nil`, you can use that object directly without having to do I/O (i.e. a fetch request). You'd then only do a fetch request for those object IDs for with this method returned `nil` (if any).

I've done this. It works. But it's not straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (for my offline-synchronization algorythm)
[image: and have the error: **Misconfigured Property: Transactions.object must have a destination entity**]

**Misconfigured Property: Transactions.object must have a destination entity** 
0_0

And think the good solve, except store ID's and name of table for search - to stored 1 of link to need-entity. Like this:
[image]
But we should not always look for the entities.
o_0

```
BEFORE
@interface Transactions : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * order;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *object;



AFTER
@interface Transactions : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * order;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Workgroup *workgroup;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AgendaItem *agendaItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Meeting *note;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Meeting *meeting;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Person *person;
```

**BUT**! If we create object and delete it - we realize that we must store type and ID ((
That means - last solve is not suitable for case with deletion entities. And solve, that belongs to my situation is:
[image: And I condemn ourselves to the constant search for the entities by table name and an ID]
And I condemn ourselves to the constant search for the entities by table name and an ID 
o_o